Ransack is not working after updated from rails4 to rails7
Polymorphic associations do not support computing the class.

I am using rails 7.0.8.4, gem 'ransack' and ruby "3.1.6"
Following code generate an error
@q = Audited::Audit.ransack(params[:q])

Note: This code was working fine in the rails 4 but not working in the rails 7

How did you update your application from Rails 4 to Rails 7? Did you follow the official update guides? Did you fix all deprecation warnings? What version of Ransack are you running?

@spickermann Yes, all the warnings are resolved and everything is working except this. I am using ransack (4.2.1).

There is an issue on GitHub in Ruby on Rails' repository. This seems to be a Rails issue (not Ransack) and it is required that you update the definition of polymorphic associations in your application.

@JigarBhatt can you tell me the ransack version ?

@PragyaSriharsh ransack (4.2.1).
